# Contents of one div in a row pushes the other Divs down

Tags: html, css

I have four columns in a row, however, when I add content to the columns, each following column is pushed down on the page. I'm unsure how I can go about fixing this.

You can get a better understanding of my problem here, I've increased box size, and reduced it to two boxes, instead of four. http://jsfiddle.net/x5zDj/

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <h1>Latest News</h1>
            <p>Lorem</p>
            <p>Lorem</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h1>Application</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Im sure there's something silly I've overlooked....

Comment: Might need to add a float: left; to your column.  http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/x5zDj/3/ *updated fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `inline-block`, you need to set the `vertical-align` to your desired property.

In your case, adding it to your `.column` css as follows corrected the issue:

```
.column {
    width: 460px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* Adding this causes them to line up evenly across the top */
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdG23/)